# Make list flat Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to do:

> Flatten a nested list structure. Transform a list, possibly holding
>   lists as elements into a 'flat' list by replacing each list with its
>   elements (recursively).
>
> Example: ?- my_flatten([a, [b, [c, d], e]], X). X = [a, b, c, d, e]
>   And my attempt:

```
unwinder([], APP, APP).
unwinder([E|Es], T, APP) :- is_list(E), unwinder(E, T,APP), unwinder(Es, T,APP). 
unwinder([E|Es], T, APP) :- \+ is_list(E),  unwinder(Es, K, APP), append( [E], T, APP).
```

I suppose that the problem is `append`, especially I still have a problem with unification :)

Please explain in terms of unification.

Comment: In your second clause, `unwinder(E, T, APP)` is saying that when you unwind `E`, the result is already the final answer, `APP`, which I can't imagine is true. Then the subsequent `unwider(Es, T, APP)` has the same arguments `T` and `APP`, so that's bound to fail. Also, be aware that `append([E], T, APP)` is simply, `[E|T] = APP`.

Comment: I don't understand, could you say something more?

Comment: You have `unwinder(E, T, APP), unwinder(Es, T, APP)` which means second argument `T` will be identical, and and third argument `APP` are going to be identical for `E` and `Es`. Is that going to be true?

Comment: The correct answer is no. But I cannot understand that.

Comment: How is `my_flatten/2` related to `unwinder/3`?

Comment: `my_flatten(L, X) :- (L, [], X).`

Comment: You mean `my_flatten(L, X) :- unwinder(L, [], X).`?

Comment: You might want to do a search on stackoverflow for `[prolog] flatten`. There are numerous Q&A posts on it, so it wouldn't make much sense for me to regurgitate it. As far as your predicate goes, I'll recommend starting from a logical perspective first before just writing predicates, as I showed in my answer to your prior question on `unwind`. You should be able to "read" your predicate in a way that it makes logical sense, describing the relation between the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing, your parameters `K`, `T` and `APP` have a messy in your predicate. In the second case:

```
unwinder([E|Es], T, APP) :- \+ is_list(E),  unwinder(Es, K, APP), append( [E], T, APP).
```

You go recursively to get `K` (i think) but never use it.

I re-write (a little) your code:

```
unwinder([], []).
unwinder([E|ES], APP) :-
    is_list(E), !,
    unwinder(E, K1),
    unwinder(ES, K2),
    append(K1, K2, APP). 
unwinder([E|ES], [E|K]) :-
    unwinder(ES, K).
```

First. Empty case.

Second. If the element is a list, go recursively through it and recursively through the rest of the list (`ES`). Then append the unified lists (`K1` & `K2`).

Third. Don't check is list (you did it before), `cons` (`|`) the element (not a list) with unified list `K`.

Note: The `!` symbol don't let go back the execution (backtracking) before that point. So, if the predicate fails in some point of second case, it can't go back to try the thrid.