# Display list of list prolog

Tags: prolog

I can't display list of list in prolog please help me for example :
I have this list :
[[1,2,3][4,5][6,8,7][6,9]]
I want to delete this [ [] [] [] [] ] and just display content:
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 6 9

I have tried this

```
WriteListe([]).
write_liste([X|Xs]) :-
 format('-~w~n', [X]),
 write_liste(Xs).
```

But when i call WriteListe(L) i have this result 
L=[]
-_6782
L = [_6782]
.....

?
Thanks you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make list flat Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367210/make-list-flat-prolog)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That one has a very bad answer....

Comment: Use `flatten/2`.

Comment: *I want to delete this `[ [] [] [] [] ]` and just display content:...*. This sounds like you have an implementation already? If so, you should show that code so people can offer specific recommendations. This question is otherwise too vague. Your syntax for lists, by the way, is incorrect. Elements need to be separated by commas.

Comment: WriteListe([]).
write_liste([X|Xs]) :-
 format('-~w~n', [X]),
 write_liste(Xs).   but when i call my list WriteListe(L) i have -_6782   -_6794.....

Comment: Please... edit your question and put your code there. Don't put it in the comments.

Comment: You just entered `write_liste(L).` with `L` a variable? Then I would expect the results you're seeing. BTW, you have typographical errors. Your predicate is `write_liste/1` not `WriteListe/1`. `WriteListe/1` would be a Prolog syntax error.

Comment: Keep appending/(adding in head) every value from the list to a new variable and you have it.

Comment: If you don't want to use `flatten/2`, you could just check if `X` is a list and recursively call `write_liste/1` on `X` if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Every non-empty list `[A|B]` consists of its head element `A` and the rest of its elements, a list `B`. Otherwise it is an empty list, `[]`:

```cpp
write_liste(X):-                        /* e.g. write_liste([[1,2,3],[4,5]). */
   X = [A|B] -> write_liste( ... ),     /* recurse on "car"                  */
                write_liste( ... ) ;    /* recurse on "cdr"                  */
   X = []    -> true /* skip it */ ; 
   /* else */   format('~w ', X).       /* we've reached the list's fringe   */
```

Try to fill in the blanks.

In lisp this is  informally known as `car` ⁄ `cdr` recursion. We process the "`car`" i.e. the head element, and the `cdr` i.e. the rest of the elements. And if it can't be taken apart, then it's an atomic element. Since each chain of such `cons` nodes (`[A|B]` in Prolog) ends in a sentinel value, an empty list `[]` which also cannot be taken apart, we skip *that*, as we're interested only in the actual elements, not in any artificial effects of representation.

Put another way, `[]` is *empty*, so there's nothing in it to be printed.